# For vs For Each Loop Behaviour - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I was searching google to find a function to be able to detect the reoccurrence of elements in array. I found the following solution:

```
var arr = ["dog","dog","cat","lion","dog","cat" ]
arr.forEach(function(x) { 
    counts[x]= (counts[x] || 0)+1
});
console.log(counts);
```

The **output** of the above is:

```
 Object {dog: 3, cat: 2, lion: 1}
```

While when using a simple **FOR loop**:

```
for(var x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
    counts[x]= (counts[x] || 0)+1
}
console.log(counts);
```

The **output** of the above is:

```
Object {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}
```

**Issues:**

Firstly I don't completly understand what is happening here:

```
counts[x]= (counts[x] || 0)+1
```

Secondly how does in a ForEach loop it is able to detect reoccurrence of elements? Is this already built in?

In the below code the property names dog, cat and lion only appears once.

```
Object {dog: 3, cat: 2, lion: 1}
```

While here the property name appears separately for each item in the array.

```
Object {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}
```

**Maybe I don't understand how the ForEach loop works but why is the behaviour of both loops different? The for each loop seems to detect repeating property names?**

Comment: in `forEach` passed _value_, in `for` loop over _index_

Comment: @Grundy thank you so much for the reply. If you don't mind could you explain whats happening in this piece of code counts[x]= (counts[x] || 0)+1 How does this code detect the reoccurrence of elements is something I don't understand. I assume to detect repeating elements one would use something like if/else statements.

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn: That's not the question you asked. If you want to ask *that* question, post it separately. Alexander has answered the question you actually asked (why do the loops behave differently).

Comment: `count[x]`: try get property `x` from `count` object, then check it `(counts[x] || 0)` - this return `0` if `counts[x]` is _falsey_, and update value in `counts[x]` with incremented value.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I doubt any community on stack exchange will allow me to ask a question on topics like "explain this piece of code". If there is such community then can you please let me know.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, actually this asked in question: _Firstly I don't completly understand what is happening here:_

Comment: @Grundy: As you probably know, a question must have **one** specific thing it's asking. In this case, the title and the boldface say it's the difference between `for` and `forEach`. (We should have closed it as "unclear.")

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, i not sure that we **should** close, but seems you right, this a different question about `counts[x]= (counts[x] || 0)+1` that would be closed as duplicated i think :-)

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn: No, if you quoted the loop and said "I don't understand how `counts[x]= (counts[x] || 0)+1` works" (ideally going into a bit more detail about what you've read or looked at to figure it out), that would be entirely on-topic for SO.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you so much for the comment and the answer. Im just about to read your answer. I will in future ask a separate questions. At times I have been voted down for asking such questions so I tend to avoid asking. Again thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've asked two different questions:

- Why do you get different results using `for` and `Array#forEach`?
- How does `counts[x]= (counts[x] || 0)+1` work?

#### Why do you get different results using `for` and `Array#forEach`?

[Alexander has answered the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33409951/157247), but just for completeness, it's because `x` in your `for` loop is the *key* (index) for that loop iteration (`0`, `1`, `2`, and so on); but `x` in your `Array#forEach` callback is the **value** for that loop iteration (`"dog"`, `"dog"`, `"cat"`, and so on).

Assuming a non-sparse array, the `for` equivalent of

```
theArray.forEach(function(value) {
    // ...do something with value
});
```

is

```
var index, value;
for (index = 0; index < theArray.length; ++index) {
    value = theArray[index];
    // ...do something with value
}
```

...except of course with the `for` example we're declaring two variables we don't declare with the `forEach` example.

For what you're doing, you want the *value*, not the index, so if you wanted to use a `for` loop, it should be:

```
var x;
for(var index=0; index<arr.length; index++){
    x = arr[index];
    counts[x]= (counts[x] || 0)+1
}
console.log(counts);
```

#### How does `counts[x]= (counts[x] || 0)+1` work?

You haven't shown how `counts` is initialized, but I'm assuming it's

```
var counts = {};
```

or

```
var counts = []; // (This would mostly be wrong, but it works)
```

So that means, if `x` is `"dog"`, `counts[x]` will be `undefined`, because `counts` doesn't start out having a property called `dog` in it. Then you do this:

```
counts[x]= (counts[x] || 0)+1
```

...which is

```
counts[x]= (counts["dog"] || 0)+1
```

...which is

```
counts[x]= (undefined || 0)+1
```

JavaScript's `||` operator is [curiously powerful](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html): It evaluates the left-hand side and, if that's "truthy", takes the left-hand side as its result; if the left-hand side is "falsey", the operator evaluates the right-hand side and takes that as its result. The "truthy" values are all values that aren't "falsey"; the "falsey" values are `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`.

So that means `undefined || 0` is `0`, because `undefined` is falsey, and we have:

```
counts[x]= (0)+1
```

...which is

```
counts[x]= 1
```

So now, `counts[x]` (where `x` is `"dog"`) contains `1`.

The *next* time you do that for `x = "dog"`, you have

```
counts[x]= (counts[x] || 0)+1
```

...which is

```
counts[x]= (counts["dog"] || 0)+1
```

...which is

```
counts[x]= (1 || 0)+1
```

Since `1` is *truthy*, `1 || 0` is `1`, so we have:

```
counts[x]= (1)+1
```

...which is

```
counts[x]= 2
```

This continues, and so it counts up the number of times you see `"dog"` in the array (and also `"cat"`, `"lion"`, etc.).

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much for this! I really understood this! Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

First argument in forEach callback is `value` not `index`

```js
var arr = ["dog","dog","cat","lion","dog","cat" ]
var forEachCounts = {};

arr.forEach(function(x) { 
    forEachCounts[x]= (forEachCounts[x] || 0)+1
});

console.log(forEachCounts);


var forCount = {};
for(var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
    forCount[arr[x]] = (forCount[arr[x]] || 0)+1
}
console.log(forCount);
```